# How to prove that for some $\epsilon >0 \; \exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ka - [ka]$ for any irrational $a$?

Tags: real-analysis

As the title states, I wonder how I could prove that for some $\epsilon >0 \; \exists k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ka - [ka]$ for any irrational $a$. Where $[x]$ would be the floor function of a real number $x$.

Comment: Should this maybe read "$|ka-[ka]|<\epsilon"$?

Comment: Wouldn't it be $0 \leq ka-[ka] < 1$. $[x] \leq x < [x]+1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq x - [x] < 1$

Comment: Your statement doesn't involve $\epsilon$ in any way...I'm trying to guess where it fits in.  Also, I expect you mean to fix $a$ from the start...presumably you don't expect a single $k$ to work for all $a$.

Comment: Yes the $a$ is fixed and it's not for all $\epsilon > 0$ but basically for some given one.

Comment: I believe that what you mean to ask is this "given $a\in \mathbb R - \mathbb Q$, show that, for any $\epsilon>0$ $\exists k\in \mathbb N$ such that $|\;ka-[ka]|<\epsilon$.  Of course, I might be misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking, also English is not my native language so my wording won't be perfect.

Comment: So, the question, then is that the fractional part of $ka$ should be dense...that is true, and has been asked before on this site, eg, here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903142/for-an-irrational-number-a-the-fractional-part-of-na-for-n-in-mathbb-n-is