# Decimal representation begins with $N$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a \geq 2$ be a positive integer such that $\log_{10}a$ is irrational. Then for any positive integer $N$ there exist infinitely many powers $a^n$ of $a$ whose decimal representation begins with $N$.

I am not sure how to use the fact that $a^n$ begins with $N$. How should I prove this?

Answer (score 2):

If $\log_{10}(a)\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, by setting $r_n=n\cdot\log_{10}(a)$ and considering the sequence
$$ r_n\pmod{1}$$
we have that such a sequence is dense in the interval $(0,1)$ by the Dirichlet's box principle.
 It follows that for infinite values of $n$ 
$$ r_n \in M_n+\left(\log_{10} 3,\;\log_{10} 4\right), \qquad M_n\in\mathbb{N}^* $$
holds, so $ 10^{r_n} = a^n $ lies between $3\cdot 10^{M_n}$ and $4\cdot 10^{M_n}$ and the first decimal digit of $a^n$ is $3$.

Obviously you may replace $3$ with any digit $\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and the same argument still applies. Moreover, with a minor fix (by working with $\log_{100}$, $\log_{1000}$ and so on) we may also prove that the initial substring of the decimal representation can be any substring not starting with a zero.

Comment: (+1) Nice! I was just thinking about using $\log_{10}(a)\notin \mathbb{Q}$ too, you are fast.

Comment: Can you explain how $r_n$ is dense in $(0,1)$ using the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: @Puzzled417: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843763/a-dense-set-on-0-1

Comment: @Puzzled417 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903142/for-an-irrational-number-a-the-fractional-part-of-na-for-n-in-mathbb-n-is This has been on this site several times.

Comment: How do you get $r_n \in M_n+\left(\log_{10} 3,\;\log_{10} 4\right), \qquad M_n\in\mathbb{N}^* $?

Comment: @Puzzled417 That's the consequence of $r_n$ being dense in $(0,1)$.

Comment: But that means that $r_n$ could lie in like $(4,5)$, which isn't a subset of $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Puzzled417 $r_n$ is considered modulo $1$. That means you can consider $r_n$ as a **fractional part** of $n\log_{10}(a)$.

Comment: @i707107 Right, and how can the fractional part lie outside of $[0,1)$?

Comment: @Puzzled417 No, that does not happen. A fractional part always lies in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Puzzled417 I see your point. Maybe I didn't understand $r_n$ correctly. It seems that $r_n$ is **exactly** equals to $n\log_{10}(a)$, and its fractional parts are dense in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Also, I think $n$ is supposed to be a positive integer? So how are you getting $10^{r_n} = a^n$?

Comment: @Puzzled417: $$ 10^{r_n} = 10^{n\cdot \log_{10}(a)} = a^n.$$