# Is the set $\{\textrm{fractional part of } n\sqrt{2}|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ dense in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fractional-part

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m$ is unequal to $n$ then the fractional part of $m\sqrt{2}$ is unequal to the fractional part of $n\sqrt{2}$. So my questions is:
is it true that the set $\{\textrm{fractional part of } n\sqrt{2}|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in
$[0,1]$?
My intuition is yes, however, I have no idea how to even begin.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem

Comment: [Yes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/843763/815585)#

Comment: Surely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true.

Let $S:=\{$fractional part of $n\sqrt{2}~|~ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.
And we denote the fractional part of $r\in \mathbb{R}$ as $0\le F(r)<1$.

In fact for  $\epsilon>0$, we take an integer $N$ s.t. $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$ and by pigeonhole principle and your argument there is a $1\le k< N$ s.t. there are two or more elemtnts in $S\cap [\frac{k}{N}, \frac{k+1}{N}]$. Now there elements denote $F(n\sqrt{2}), F(m\sqrt{2})$ ($n<m$).
Then $0<a:=F((m-n)\sqrt{2})<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$.

Now for all $0\le x\le 1$,  we write $x$ as $x=Ma+y$ where $M\in \mathbb{N}, 0\le y<a$. Then $x-F(M(m-n)\sqrt{2})=x-Ma=y<\epsilon$.
So $S$ is dense in [0,1].