# Can every terminating rational number be approximated with a square root?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am interested in proving the following theorem. Let $q$ be a terminating rational number. Then there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{m}+n$ begins with $q$. To give an example given a rational number $0.123$ the decimal expansion of $\sqrt{17}-4$ begins with $0.123$.

I have managed to prove this statement under the assumption that $\sqrt{2}$ is a normal number. Can this theorem be proven unconditionally?

Comment: Whether $\sqrt{2}$ is normal , cannot be decided with the current known tools. But that every rational number can be approximated in the desired way , should relatively easy be provable.

Comment: I think you want to assume that $q$ is a terminating decimal (non-repeating still leaves open the possibility that the decimal is infinite). This is indeed provable: we're aiming for a window of size $10^{-k}$ where $k$ is the length of $q$, but the difference between $\sqrt m$ and $\sqrt{m+1}$ becomes less than $10^{-k}$ when $m$ is large enough.

Comment: The author only wants an approximation that begins with a given finite digit string. And the $\bar 0$ ambiguity is no problem here. In this context it is clear that we have only to deal with finite digitstrings, so terminating number (being written without the artificial $\bar 0$)

Comment: It's silly to phrase questions like this in terms of decimal expansion. Much more to the point to directly ask about $\varepsilon$-close approximation. "Terminating" is irrelevant to the maths of interest here.

Comment: The answers are all fine (+1). I just want to remark that I think the claim follows already from the density of the numbers of the form
$$m\sqrt2+n=\sqrt{2m^2}+n.$$ See [this oldie](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73262/11619). Here $m,n$ obviously range over the integers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't understand one thing. When $m$ is negative then $m\sqrt{2}$ is not the same as $\sqrt{2m^2}$. What am I missing?

Comment: A good point, Adam. I missed it. The same problem in Oscar's answer. I like to think it can be fixed...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. Let $ \phi(x)$ denote the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $x.$ Since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, $ \left\{ \phi\left(n\sqrt{2}\right) : n\in\mathbb{N} \right\} $ [is a dense subset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843763/for-x-in-mathbb-r-setminus-mathbb-q-the-set-nx-lfloor-nx-rfloor-n-in-ma?rq=1) of $[0,1],\ $ i.e. $ \left\{ \phi\left(\sqrt{2n^2}\right) : n\in\mathbb{N} \right\} $ is a dense subset of $[0,1].\ $

Comment: So how should I understand the fractional part of the expression $(\{n\sqrt2\}\colon n\in\mathbb{N})$...?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I can see how the notation might be confusing. $ \left\{ \left\{n\sqrt{2}\right\} : n\in\mathbb{N} \right\} $ is the *set* of fractional parts of numbers of the form $n\sqrt{2}\ $ for positive integers $n.$ So, the fractional part of $\sqrt{2}\ $ is one member of the set, the fractional part of $2\sqrt{2}\ $ is another member of the set, the fractional part of $3\sqrt{2},\ $ is another member of the set, etc. So the set is: $\{\ 0.4142\ldots,\  0.8284\ldots,\ 0.2426\ldots,\ \ldots\ \}.$

Comment: It would be a lot less confusing if you hadn't chosen $\{\cdot\}$, of all notations. What's wrong with $\operatorname{fr}(x)$ or $\phi(x)$ or whatever else that doesn't look like a set bracket?

Comment: $\{\cdot\}$ is the standard notation for fractional part of $x.$ Apparently at least $7$ other people did not find my answer confusing. However, I do actually agree with you that it might be confusing especially for those unfamiliar with the standard notation for fractional part, and I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 21):

Note that $(\sqrt{m} - \sqrt{m-1}) \downarrow 0$, so for $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $M(\varepsilon)$ such that for every $ m \ge M$,

$$(\sqrt{m} - \sqrt{m-1}) < \varepsilon$$

Suppose that the rational number is $q = 0.a_1a_2...a_l$ with $a_i \in \{0,...,9\}$. Then, let $\varepsilon < 10^{-(l+1)}$ and WLOG letting $M(\varepsilon) = k^2$ be a square for convenience, consider $[\sqrt{m} ]$ for $n = k^2, ..., (k+1)^2-1$, where $[x]$ is taken to denote the fractional part of $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Further WLOG let  $M$ be sufficiently large such that $[\sqrt{(k+1)^2-1}] > q+ \varepsilon$.

Then, $([\sqrt{m}])$  is an increasing sequence of numbers in $[0,1]$ which exceeds $q+\varepsilon$, but with the consecutive difference strictly upper-bounded by $\varepsilon$. Hence, we must have an element of the sequence in $[q, q+ \varepsilon]$, which will therefore have the same first $l$ digits as $q$ in its decimal expansion.

Thus, $\sqrt{m}$ as above and $n = -\lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor$ is sufficient.

Not as clever as Adam's answer, but to its credit, this approach is constructive.

Comment: Adam's answer essentially says 'here is a link to a theorem that says it's true' whereas you actually prove the theorem.

Comment: Your answer is just as nice/"clever" in my opinion.

Answer (score 11):

Start with a quadratic surd that is less than $1$, such as $\sqrt2-1$. Raise it to a high power so as to get a very small number guaranteed to have the form $a-b\sqrt2$. Say we use $21$ as the exponent getting

$(\sqrt2-1)^{21}=-54608393+38613965\sqrt2\approx9.1561×10^{-9}$

Now multiply by a whole number that gets you close to the decimal you want to approximate, for instance

$0.123/(\sqrt2-1)^{21}\approx13433665$

$(\sqrt2-1)^{21}×13433665=-685229663750345+422004682131725\sqrt2\approx0.123000003$

The lower you dare to go with the power of the less than unit quadratic surd, the better you can approximate a given decimal.

Comment: I think I have spotted an issue with your method. If your method spits out the approximation $a-b\sqrt{2}$ where $b$ is positive, it may not be possible to express it as $\sqrt{m}+n$ for some integers $m$ and $n$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: $m=2b^2$, of course.

Comment: I am probably being stupid but isn't $\sqrt{2b^2} = b\sqrt{2}$ rather than $-b\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Failed to note that the positive square root was asked. Will need to try again

Comment: @OscarLanzi can't you just replace $20$ by $21$ (or any odd exponent)?

Comment: I could, but I have yo regenerate my calculation sheet. This requires a block of time.

Comment: A few months ago I developed an extension of this technique which quickly finds good approximations, but (of course) you need high precision arithmetic. Eg, $$\pi \approx 3.14159265358979 \approx 4375636191520 \sqrt2 - 6188084046055$$ https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLVLBVMDE2NzUzNjO0NDQ1MlDQUiguLCrRMNJU0FUwM7SwMLAwMTAxMzA15eUqKMrMK9FI1MvTsDTT1AQAilgNoA==&lang=sage